# Use type checking to check that string is of certain values only

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Suppose I have a python function `def func_AB(param1: str)`. `param1` can only take on values `A` or `B`. If it takes on any other string value, an error should appear.

Is it possible to use python type checking to give out error when this happens? Currently, I use `assert` to check that `param1` contains the valid string value.

I am using python 3.8.5

Comment: If you're restricted to only a few valid values, why not [use an enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) instead of a string?

Comment: if you're looking at 2 possible valid values, you're not really type checking

Comment: @ Green Cloak Guy, good point. I asked a stupid question. Wrong from the start.

Comment: Type checking is for checking the `type`, not the `value`. Also, type checking is only enforced by a IDE. python doesn't natively enforce type checking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you're looking for [Literal](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/literal_types.html#literal-types)

```
from typing import Literal

def func_AB(param1: Literal['A', 'B']):
    ...
```

Comment: You are amazing. I thought no answer exists based on the comments. I wish I can give you more points. Haha.